# Aggregating data using R, having a little trouble

Tags: r

I have data in the following format-

Group - individual - meals purchased - money spent - date

1  - Joe - 3 - 25 - Tuesday

1 - Jane - 2 - 40 - Tuesday

1 - Joe - 4 - 50 - Sunday

2 - Sam - 3 - 60 - Sunday

2- Sally - 3 - 30 - Tuesday

What I would like to do is to collapse the data by group so that I know the number of meals purchased and money spent by the total group on a given day.

I am using the following code in r -

```
Newdata <- aggregate (data, by  = list (data$Group, data$date), FUN=sum)
```

This is not working unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Newdata <- aggregate (data$meals, by  = list (data$Group, data$date), FUN=sum)
```

For a `data.table` solution, try:

```
setDT(data)
data[,all_meals:= sum(meals), by = list(Group, date)]
```

For multiple columns at once, I think you can do this:

```
Newdata <- aggregate (cbind(data$meals, data$money), by  = list(data$Group, data$date), FUN=sum)
```

Or:

```
setDT(data)
data[,lapply(.SD, sum), by=list(Group, date), .SDcols=c(meals, money)
```

I can't be 100% sure it will work, given that you didn't actually provide us with any data.

Comment: This worked like a charm, is there a way to do two columns at once?  For example meals and cost?  I tried to do more than one column to be aggregated but it did not work. for example data$meals, data$money, by = list....

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
Newdata <- aggregate (data[,3], by  = list (data$Group, data$date), FUN=sum)
```

Comment: This worked well, but is there a way to do two columns at once?  For example meals and cost?  I tried to do more than one column to be aggregated but it did not work; for example data$meals, data$money, by = list....

Comment: @JWH2006 try `cbind(data[,3],data[,4])` or use your column names like `cbind(data$purchased,data$spent)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` solution which also sums two columns:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), individual = c("Joe",  "Jane", "Joe", "Sam", "Sally"), meals = c(3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L),      money = c(25L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 30L), date = c("Tuesday", "Tuesday",      "Sunday", "Sunday", "Tuesday")), .Names = c("Group", "individual",  "meals", "money", "date"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -5L))

data %>%
    group_by(Group, date) %>%
    mutate(all_meals = sum(meals), tot_cost = sum(money)) %>%
    ungroup

##  # A tibble: 5 × 7
##   Group individual meals money    date all_meals tot_cost
##   <int>      <chr> <int> <int>   <chr>     <int>    <int>
## 1     1        Joe     3    25 Tuesday         5       65
## 2     1       Jane     2    40 Tuesday         5       65
## 3     1        Joe     4    50  Sunday         4       50
## 4     2        Sam     3    60  Sunday         3       60
## 5     2      Sally     3    30 Tuesday         3       30
```